# Запись результата, от регулярных выражений в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, re

Как данные из **регулярного выражения** записать в *файл*?.

```
def main():
    fil_nam()
    with open(r'latest.log') as f:
        while True:
            for line in f:
                if re.search('\[CHAT\]',line):
                    print(line.strip())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

data = open('kek', 'r').read().split('\n')
open('result.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF-8').write('\n'.join([x.strip() for x in data if re.findall(r'\[CHAT\]', x)]))
```

Comment: не) мне нужно именно результат от line.strip()  в файл записать а ваш метод записывает именно "[CHАT]" а не всю строку в которой находится [CHАT]

Comment: простите за тавтологию

Comment: @Nuub228, Обновил ответ.